# Duplicate toolbar when trying to implement NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-xml

I'm trying to integrate a navigation drawer with my relative layout (which holds my activity content) and my toolbar. As you can see below, the toolbar is being duplicated within the interior relative layout as well as existing outside of it.

The highlighted portion is the relative layout.
Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/landing_page"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/frontPageBGColor">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">


                //Content Content Content

                </RelativeLayout>



            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
                android:name="com.xxxxxxxx.chessgame.NavigationDrawerFragment"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That might be an action bar, you need to hide that.

Comment: It seems more like the toolbar is being stretched down into the relative layout

Comment: @RU92Z I am guessing that a fragment that you inflated has a toolbar

Answer (score 4):

in your styles, you need to inherit the app theme from .NoTitleBar to remove the system provided action bar

like this

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

explained in detail here:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: Thank you for this. Wasn't aware the toolbar was so tightly knit to the theme.